# How to do ADF data binding for Swing Components in JDeveloper 12 c?

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, bc4j

as there is no drag and drop feature not available for Swing data Bindings from Data Control in JDeveloper 12c ,how to do it tell me clearly if possible i am new to Oracle ADF or  provide any resources for learning that swing components binding.

thank you in advance .

Comment: Start with the docs? https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFSW/introduction.htm#ADFSW109.  Also, I believe swing support for adf binding is deprecated. You should use adf faces instead.

Comment: but for Desktop Application Creation , is ADF Swing is the Only Possibility or any other technologies  Available ?

Comment: Docs section 4 clearly states data binding is available for Swing - just not through drag and drop. About Working With Data Binding

Answer (score 1):

ADF Swing binding is deprecated in 12 - instead you should use "regular" swing development to bind to backend data.